# Constructible angles

Tags: field-theory, geometric-construction

What are the constructible angles ?

[Wikipidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_and_straightedge_constructions#Constructible_angles)
sais:

> The only angles of finite order that may be constructed starting with two points are those whose order is either a power of two, or a product of a power of two and a set of distinct Fermat primes.

I don't understand  the *exact* meaning of this, does it say that an angle is constructible *if and only if* it is a power of two or a product of a power and $?$ (this part I didn't understand either)

Comment: That is the theorem, yes, if and only if.   A less fancy way of putting it is for $n$ a positive integer, the angle $2\pi/n$ is constructible iff $n$ is a power of $2$ (possibly equal to $1$) times a product (possibly empty) of distinct Fermat primes. The order stuff generalizes this in an unimportant way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas not really. The angle 98 degrees =  6π/10 is constructible, but your way doesn't include it.

Comment: @Ekuurh: $6\pi/10$ is $108^\circ$...

Comment: @Ekuurh: Our disagreement would be over whether going beyond the constructible polygons is an important generalization.

Comment: @J.M. Honest mistake :)
Yea, I think the set of all constructible angles should be classified.

Comment: 98 degrees can not be constructible. We know that 90*11/10=99 degrees is constructible , and if 98 degrees is constructible, then 1 degree would be constructible, and 20 degrees would be constructible, which contradicts the classic proof of the impossibility of trisecting an arbitrary angle with a compass and straightedge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means an angle is constructible if and only if its order is either a power of two, or a power of two times a set of Fermat primes.
For example, 10 = 2*5, and 2 is a power of two and 5 is a fermat prime, thus you can make an angle of 360/10 = 36 degrees.
but 40 degrees = 360/9 cannot be constructed, because 9=3*3, and 3, 3 are not distinct.

Comment: This means that $2^0$ is ok in both cases ?

Comment: Sure, $2^0$ is fine, $0$ is a good number, perhaps a little too unassuming.

Comment: @Belgi Yea, it's fine, and by accepting that 1 is a power of 2, we get that the constructible angles are exactly the angles whose order is a power of two times a set of distinct Fermat primes.

Comment: What does order of an angle mean?